# Why passing a pointer by reference here causes an error?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I have a template node class:

```
template<typename T>
class TNode {
    T data;
    TNode<T>* left;
    TNode<T>* right;
public:
    TNode() {   left = right = nullptr; }
    TNode(T d) {    data = d;   left = right = nullptr; }
    void setData(T d) { data = d; }
    T getData() {   return data;    }
    void setLeft(TNode<T>* l) {     left = l;   }
    TNode<T>* getLeft() {   return left;    }
    void setRight(TNode<T>* r) {    right = r;  }
    TNode<T>* getRight() {  return right;   }
};
```

Which I am using to build the following binary search tree :

```
template<typename T>
class BSTree
{
private:
    TNode<T>* root;
    void rec_insertBST(TNode<T>*& subRoot, int key)
    {
        if (subRoot == nullptr)
            subRoot = new TNode<T>(key);
        else if (subRoot->getData() < key)
            rec_insertBST(subRoot->getRight(), key);
        else
            rec_insertBST(subRoot->getLeft(), key);
    }
public:
    void insertBST(int key)
    {
        rec_insertBST(root, key);
    }
};
```

when I pass pointer to insert function by reference (**&**) I get this compilation error :

> 'void BSTree::rec_insertBST(TNode *&,int)': cannot convert
> argument 1 from 'TNode *' to 'TNode *&'

But when I remove the reference operator (**&**) It compiles successfully. Why does this happen and how can I pass pointer by reference here ?

Even if the code doesn't make sense I want explanation for the error please.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the pointer by reference? Pass by pointer or by reference...

Comment: @Thrasher probably because of the `subRoot = new TNode<T>(key);` maybe the OP want that `root` that is passed here `rec_insertBST(root, key)` reflects the modification.

Comment: This is a simple code sample for the question but in the real class i pass pointer by reference for destructing the tree or editing the pointers to point to another node.

Comment: You can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary. Either return references from the getters or use public members. ([Here](https://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) is an interesting article about "quasi-classes" like this.)

Comment: Sidenote: Be aware that the standard container [<map>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is usually implemented as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) internally, so your work on this `BSTree` might be wasted time.

Comment: @molbdnilo so the getters are returning copies.. that's the reason? I didn't expect compiler to be that smart ..

Comment: @DevSolar I am a student taking data structure course :)

Comment: @OffensiveRook There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: @OffensiveRook `so the getters are returning copies.. that's the reason? I didn't expect compiler to be that smart ..` as long as you don't have a `&` in your return c++ always returns a copy of what you return. So in your case, a copy of the `TNode<T>*` pointer is returned. (The same is true for `T getData()` where a copy of `T` is returned.

Comment: @t.niese Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @OffensiveRook: Well then, perhaps tell your instructor to teach you what the standard library already provides, and how to use it effectively, instead of teaching you to reinvent the wheel. ;-)  And *if* your instructor sets you to creating a container class, it should "look" like a C++ container, not a Java container... ;-) (No offense intended to either you or your instructor. I've just seen too many of such "reimplement the standard" assignments, which really don't teach what *should* be taught for either app or library coders...)

Comment: @DevSolar Agreed. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getLeft` method returns a **copy** of the `left` member variable, so even if your code compiled it would not alter `left`. However it doesn't compile because of the rule that you cannot bind a reference to a temporary.

Several solutions are possible, the one that seems the best to me is to replace `getLeft` with `left` and `getRight` with `right`.

```
       rec_insertBST(subRoot->right, key);
```

This will require changing access permissions or granting friendship.

Another alternative would be to have `getLeft` and `getRight` return references.